# Keeping the order of insertion In Map object after deleting elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**My Findings:**

`object.forEach` loop is messing up order of element (ascending and descending) but for loop is working fine. Does anyone else experienced it too ? or any explanation about it ? I think JavaScript does not guarantee property order of objects.

**What I am trying to achieve ?**
I have an array of type string which is sorted in descending order.

```
words: string[] = [];
words = this.getSomeStringArray();
word.sort();
word.reverse();
```

I have then passed this array to a function named `countWordFrequency()` as below.

```
private CountWordFrequency(words: string[]) : Map<string, number> {
    let mapObject: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

    for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
      !mapObject.has(words[i]) ? mapObject.set(words[i], 1) :
      mapObject.set(words[i], mapObject.get(words[i]) + 1); 
    }

    console.log(mapObject);
    return mapObject;
  }
```

I have used for loop here because `forEach` was messing again with the order of words array so with for loop i avoided it and performed insertion so that keys (string) are in descending order and number here  presents how many times that word occurred in words array. After this I am calling this function which will first get  values from the Map object in `valueArray` and then it sort in descending order and keep first 5 eliminating rest of them. Then in a `forEeach` on `mapObject` I am checking if the map element has value equals to that array keep it else delete it. to this it is fine but again in this operation that descending order of insertion is messed up. Here is the function.

```
 private identifyTopFive(mapObject: Map<string, number>) : Map<string, number> {
    let valueArray: number[] = [];

    //Get all values from the map in array.
    valueArray = Array.from(mapObject.values());

    //Sort them in descending order.
    valueArray.sort( (a,b)=> { return b-a });

    //Delete duplicate values from array.
    valueArray = valueArray.filter((element, index, self)=> {
      return index == self.indexOf(element);
    });

    //Get only first 5 values in array and discard rest.
    valueArray = valueArray.slice(0,5);

    //Delete elements from the mapObject whose values who are not Top 5.

        mapObject.forEach((key,value,mapObject) => {
          if(!valueArray.includes(key))
          mapObject.delete(value);
      });

    console.log(valueArray);
    console.log(mapObject);
    return null;
  }
```

This there any technique to keep this **descending order** or any other data structure that I can use to keep the **descending order** of string values along with their occurrence.

**Solved**

The problem was with the data structures I have been using and not the forEach loop. I converted my map object to an array of objects and sorted it based upon the value in descending order, this worked for me.

Comment: *"I have used for loop here because forEach was messing again with the order of words array so with for loop i avoided it and performed insertion so that keys (string) are in descending order and number here presents how many times that word occurred in words array."* `forEach` definitely visits entries in the same order that loop does.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). You keep saying the order is "messed up" but without saying what order you're seeing and what you expect again. Just FWIW, `Array#forEach` isn't broken; neither is `Map#forEach`. `Map` objects maintain their entries in the order of insertion. Beyond that, we need that MCVE with sample data, output, and expected output in order to help you.